# how to trigger elements inside directive template from outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am not able to access the dom elements outside the app.js, that are created by the directive, what should be done? please suggest the best approach, as i am new to angularjs

```
app.directive('myMenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: ' <div class="sticky-wrapper"><div class="sticky-menu">   menu</div></div>'
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dwyu78Ln/3/)

Comment: what are you trying to do with them? The elements wont be there when that javascript executes. Add to you question more about what you are trying to do.Usually you would have a "link" function property of that directive that manipulates the dom

Comment: in my actual project, the directive is created for the menu bar, i need the "sticky-wrapper" dom in my main.js to initialize sticky

Comment: If you want to execute javascript on the dom elements, add a link property with a function that does what you want. To the directive definition that is

Comment: but i want to add the js for that in a separate main.js file.. how to do that?

Comment: if you HAVE to have the functionality in that file, and it is 100% outside of your angular code, you would still want to call that code from within your  directive. You could make it global or something like that. The best solution would probably be to wrap that global in an angular service to inject into anything that might use it. Then here call it from your directive link

Comment: basically the only way to 100% make sure the elements are there when running that code would be to explicitly check for them on an interval or to use the post compile "link" functionality for your directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `$(document).ready(function() {` like below:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwyu78Ln/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var orgElementPos = $('.sticky-wrapper').offset();
  alert(orgElementPos.top);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('myMenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: ' <div class="sticky-wrapper"><div class="sticky-menu">   menu</div></div>',
    link: function(element){
            var orgElementPos = $('.sticky-wrapper').offset().top;
        alert(orgElementPos);
    }
    };
});
```

Comment: without knowing what specifically you are trying to do its a little tough but usually this is what you would do. Also I suggest getting familiar with the default angular api so you dont need to use jquery.